# GCM implementation doubts

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to GCM and relatively new to Android programming also. I am trying to implement push notification. I have the gcm_reg_no in my MySQL database.

Now I want to send the push notifications to these registration IDs. Can you please help me know what the next step would be? Do I need to add anything in the Android part of the project? Or do I just have to send the request to the GCM server with PHP?

Comment: Best place to start is the official examples. Theres a server part and client part to it. So yes, you need to do something in your Android project. [Example](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html)

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what server part of the application will be responsible for?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the GCM reg ID's from the devices posted back to your server and stored in your DB then all you have to do is pass the data to the GCM server when you want to do a push notification to them.

For example here is the function I use to send the push notifications:

```
//reg array here is an array of the GCM_reg_Ids I wish to send the push to
function push($regarr)
{

// Set POST variables
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

// Google API KEY, If you don't know your key just walk through the starter guide
$apiKey = "***************";

// Get all the message variables
// These are variables of data you send in the push notification which you use in the 
// Appcode to do stuff
$message = "test" ;
$data = "http://www.google.com";
$preheader = "New Notification";
$header = "test" ;

$fields = array(
              'registration_ids'  => $regarr,
              'data'              => array( "message" => $message,
                                            "preheader" => $preheader,
                                            "header" => $header,
                                            "data" => $data ),
              );

  $headers = array( 
                  'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                  'Content-Type: application/json'
              );

  // Open connection
  $ch = curl_init();

  // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

  // Execute post
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  // Close connection
  curl_close($ch);


  $json_return = json_decode($result);
  return $json_return;
}
```

Don't forget to make sure you have CURL enabled on your PHP, there are allot of guides out there with examples and getting started with GCM, happy push messaging :D